# Landmine detonation by air explosions?

Tags: technological-development, near-future, earth

In the story I am creating, there's a near-future Earth, where humanity is recovering from global conflict; only parts of the world have retained the science and technologies that have been widespread previously.

One of the countries that still has scientists, technology and manufacturing, and is still able to somewhat advance them, is trying to take over some previously fought over territory.

The issue they have come to now, is that the territory is heavily mined by (approximately present-day tech) AT and AP mines. We are talking vast areas - 100,000km<sup>2</sup> or more. As far as I read about demining at present day technology level, it would take exceedingly long time to disarm minefields, but the country is pressed for time.

Luckily, they have been able to advance their technologies a bit, so they researched and built missiles that can be fired over minefields, and detonate near ground, creating sufficient pressure waves that would explode most of the mines in the area of effect.

What would be needed (handwaved or so) that such missiles would be practical? As much as I looked at the existing demining processes, there is no mention of anything like that, so I presume it is quite unpractical at present time. Is there something else maybe instead of air explosions?

Comment: I'm not sure what sources you're using for your research, but mine-clearing explosives [are very much in use today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mine-clearing_line_charge), let alone the future.

Comment: @Cadence Interesting! I don't know how I missed that, thanks. Would that be practical for large areas though? I am considering minefields in total of 100'000km2 or more. Updated question to reflect that.

Comment: It makes a difference what type of terrain the enormous mined area is made up of.  Urban?  Agricultural?  Wilderness?  (Hint:  Think about who mined the area and why.  As soon as you mine an area you are either committing lots of time to clearing and recovering the mines later so you can use the territory, or effectively writing it off indefinitely.)  Also consider that enough force to reliably destroy all mines in the area will reliably kill all animals and most vegetation in the area you bomb - so what benefit is realised from destructive clearance?

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 a mix of agricultural/wilderness mostly. It was a huge frontline which was mined heavily in preparation for enemy attack.  The people who mined weren't concerned about use of the territory and were content to let it remain as a barrier for enemies. In this case, there is a combination of circumstances which make it imperative to be able to use the territory asap.

Comment: @Gnudiff what does the territory need to be used for?  Even if it is logistically feasible for the advanced country to construct and deploy enough FAE to detonate most of the anti-personnel mines, the effects of the FAE detonations and mine detonations will kill all the animals and 99% of the plant life in the area, and contaminate the soil with residues.  (Note that some AP mines will survive the FAE, as will the anti-tank mines, which will both need to be dealt with separately.)  Will try to find time to write a full answer...

Comment: A non-trivial part of why clearing minefields with modern tech takes so long is a matter of certifying an area as clear of mines, not actually neutralizing the mines. To be certain you’re safe, you have to go over the whole area with a wide array of (expensive) sensors _very slowly_ (to be absolutely certain you don’t miss anything). Actually neutralizing mines that are found is often relatively quick unless you have some special handling requirement (such as is the case with UXO’s found in [Zone rouge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_rouge) in France).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The technology you describe basically already exists, but it is not just rockets (which would probably be too expensive), but [Mine-clearing line charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mine-clearing_line_charge) a.k.a. MICLICs.

The idea is that you have a rope connecting a lot of explosives, use rocket to pull the rope(s) and explosives, creating a line of explosives on the ground which are then detonated. The gain in efficiency is that you disperse your explosives much more than if you just fired a rocket with a single explosive payload and you have a certain level of assurance that you have now created a continuous clear path through the minefield.

I think [KerrAvon's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/247805/39339) is basically right in that explosive clearing is mostly a no-go for a bunch of reasons, but if you don't like that sort of reasoning, some iteration on MICLICs (e.g. use a set of rockets/drones to pull a 2D net over a large area) might be what you need.

Comment: Came to post that they've described a MICLIC - glad to see someone else posted it.

Comment: Line clearing line charges are for breaching minefields while conflict is still ongoing. You need to do it fast, before the enemy can react. In peacetime would be unjustifiably expensive and unreliable. There are much more effective options you can employ if nobody is shooting at you.

Comment: FYI, MCLIC costs about 100$ per square meter.  Done indiscriminately over the entire region would cost about 10 trillion dollars plus labor and logistics.

Comment: Totally agree MICLIC is not very practical, it is just so close to what the OP asked for that I think it deserves a mention. I am also quite sure that if you _really_ wanted, you could make a non-combat version that's a bit more efficient (although still hugely impractical)

Answer (score 26):

**Advances in technology are your friend**

As noted in my comment on the question, trying to detonate all of the mines over such a vast area using energetic pulses from fuel air explosives (FAE) or the equivalent will render the area unusable.  (Do not even consider using conventional explosives detonating in contact with the ground, the required mass of explosive is prohibitive for such a large area.)  Buildings and utilities will be damaged, the large majority of plant and animal life in the area being cleared will die from the aerial explosions, most of the remaining life will be killed when the mines detonate, and the area will be covered in shrapnel and poisonous byproducts from the various detonations.  Which means that land that could not be used due to mines *now* cannot be used due to chemical contamination and the risk of residual mines - since explosive clearance will not detonate all of the anti-personnel mines and probably none of the anti-armour mines.  (Some current mines are designed to not be clearable by explosive means.)  This is not a great outcome.

There is no silver bullet available to deal with the problem, otherwise we would be able to quickly deal with the various minefields left around the world today.  However, there are some advances in prototype or limited use today that will help.  (Some of these may be currently more or less advanced than my understanding of the subject - my qualifications in this field are a quarter-century out of date.)

Assumption 1:  Given the stupendous size of the mined area, I assume that the vast majority of the area is made up of scatterable mines that were dropped from aircraft or deployed from artillery shells.  It is inconceivable that an area this vast could be covered by hand-laid or even vehicle-laid mines.  This makes a significant difference to the ease of detecting the mines - see step 1 and step 4 below.

Assumption 2:  I assume that the minefields are mixed, consisting of both anti-personnel and anti-armour mines.  (If they consisted of only one type or the other then clearance would be much, much easier - send armoured vehicles in to clear AP minefields and send robots or technicians out to disarm and pick up anti-armour mines.)

**Step 1:**  Precisely locate each mine and map its location.  Do this using a combination of low-pressure ground drones using chemsniffers to detect explosive traces and a combination of ground and flying drones using image recognition to identify the scatterable (ie surface-laid) mines.

**Step 2:**  Send in bomb disposal drones/robots to neutralise the mines with disruptors (ie jets of water shot at bullet speeds).  Occasionally they may make a mistake and set one off, even more occasionally the bomb disposal drone may be damaged by the detonation.

**Step 3:**  Send in an armoured, drone (ie remote-controlled) open-topped dump truck with a bunch of robot arms to pick up the disrupted mines, put them in the back of the truck and drive them to where they will be detonated in a controlled manner.  Ensure that no human and no critical infrastructure is within 1 km of a loaded truck's route, so that *when* something does go wrong there is no loss of life and limited property damage.  (If the dump truck tray is sufficiently armoured and only anti-personnel mines are detonated then the truck probably will not take much damage.)

**Step 4:**  Repeat step 1 and send the drones back in to find anything that was missed in steps 1-3.  Add ground penetrating radar to the detection array if there is a risk that there may be buried mines in a given area - best not to risk the drones with the expensive ground penetrating radar in step 1.

**Step 5:**  Send in an armoured, remote-controlled plough to thoroughly turn over the soil to get anything missed in steps 1-4.

**Step 6:**  Get everyone who will be working in the cleared area to sign waivers in order to cover yourself for the consequences of mines missed in steps 1-5.  Pay generous pensions to survivors and dependents regardless of the waivers if you want people to work in the area.  Most importantly, train people to *never, ever* pick up something they see on the ground that looks interesting, instead always take a photo from a distance and send it in to a group of clearance experts.

That is basically the plan.  How long it will take to do is dependent on how many trained people and specialised equipment can be thrown at the problem.  Throw a sufficiently large team* at an area and they could potentially clear a square kilometre per day, depending on the terrain, so with a hundred teams the whole area could be cleared in three years.  This would be the primary national focus of an economically powerful nation, but you said they need the territory ASAP.

*A team might consist of 100 low-pressure detector drones, 10 flying detector drones, 20 disruptor drones, 10 armoured dump trucks, 20 ground-penetrating radar drones and 4 armoured ploughs.  Somewhere between 100 and 200 humans would be needed for operational duties and to conduct maintenance on the drones at any time, double that if you want the drones operating 365 days per year.  Add administrative overhead appropriately as the number of teams is scaled up.

Comment: This is the correct answer because you do NOT want to actually explode all the mines where they are lain. You don't want those chemicals in the soil that you plan to resettle. Depending on the density of the mines (not that much for AT mines usually) and the quality of the detectors you can easily clear several square kilometers a day with that size of a team

Comment: @Hobbamok, depending on the explosive used, sometimes you *do* want those chemicals in the soil.  A number of explosive compounds make decent fertilizers (and vice-versa).

Comment: @Mark The explosives themselves might make for decent fertiliser, but their reaction products are much less likely to be such. For example, a common fertiliser that is also an explosive is ammonium nitrate. When it explodes, it produces nitrogen oxides and ammonia gas, neither of which are particularly good for the ecosystem, especially once that ammonia gas condenses and reaches water in its liquid form.

Comment: @Mash Certain farmers routinely inject [anhydrous ammonia](https://iowaagliteracy.wordpress.com/2019/03/20/why-do-they-do-that-anhydrous/) into their fields for fertilization. The details might be different than with land mine detonation (which may change the calculus), but adding ammonia to the ecosystem is not _prima facie_ an unmitigated bad thing.

Comment: regarding your "step 2" - wouldn't blasting a mine with high-pressure water jet set off all of its' tamper-prevention mechanisms? I'd assume the majority of munitions would detonate when "disrupted" in this way.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov apparently not, which is why they are in use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bomb_disposal#Projected_water_disruptors  Suggest that you search on "bomb disposal robot disruptor" if you want more information, and aren't too concerned about getting on watchlists :-)

Answer (score 10):

The main issue is that, due to the large acoustic impedance mismatch between air and ground, the energy transfer from air to the ground will be very ineffective.

This means that to have an appreciable effect on mines, you would need to have a large explosion in the air.

Unless you can improve the coupling between air and ground, and you could do this similarly to how it is done with echo scans. Instead of applying a layer of gel, you could flood the area with the mine field and then detonate underwater. This will make the explosion much more effective at triggering the mines and would also help contain the explosion of said mines.

What you need to handwave is then the capability of flooding large areas at will.

Comment: Interesting! That's certainly one way to approach this. 

As I understand then, anything what happens in air will have trouble affecting the ground much due to impedance -- not only shell explosions, but also sonic booms, etc, I presume some tweaks (for example, shaping the shells so that explosion is mostly directed at ground initially, etc) would also be of limited increase of use?

Comment: If you already have flooding-at-will capacity you're already done for a lot of mine types (all that operate based on pressure sensors). Just increase the flooding height until the sufficient pressure is reached

Comment: @Hobbamok I was going to say the water pressure would equalize below and above the pressure plate, but now that I think about it if the flooding is rapid enough the water wouldn't seep down into the mine before the mine can trigger.

Comment: @causative that also depends on the soil and the type of mine imho. I'm not an expert but a lot of mines are self-sealed, aka there is no "under the pressure plate" where water can seep to. That kind of mine would explode no matter the speed of flooding.  Since OP is writing this as a fiction, the widespread use of that kind of mine is entirely plausible hin their story

Answer (score 4):

**Why isn't hard: economics**

Minefield disaramanent today doesn't use weapons with large areas of effect for a number of reasons.

1. They wouldn't just affect the ground, they'd cause all kinds of trouble with overflights, transportation a horizontal distance from the explosion, etc.
2. They're inefficient because the force to disarm is delivered everywhere rather than only where a mine is.
3. In comparison, manpower is cheap. Even thousands of soldiers working to clear a large mine field would be cheaper than the carpet bombing the same area.
4. The replacement of components of mine sweepers would likely be cheaper than replacement of single-use bombs.

*But what if the economic status-quo changed?*

- What if soldiers were at a premium and deployment for mine field disarming stategically weakened other areas?
- What if bombs were developed such that their construction costs rivaled the component replacement costs of minesweepers?
- What if a technology were created that, like developments in thermal tech in the last ten years on Earth, were able to detect the mines from a pracitcal distance (e.g., 100 meters), allowing bombs to be deployed *tactically.*
- Finally, what if by "bombs" we meant something quite a bit more like the delivery and consequences of napalm? Rather than a single point explosion, what's delivered is something more like the jellied petroleum of napalm. Jellied liquid nitrogen! *(I thought of it first!)* The carpet bomping mechanism spreads said jelly across the surface where, after a few moments of thawing, it dramatically explodes (flash evaporation)! This not only spreads the effect around, but brings the explosion into the closest possible contact with the ground.

There are without doubt holes in these ideas, but let's keep something in mind: landmines are meant to be detonated with the application of only 10-20 lbs of weight. That's all we're trying to achieve. Maybe 30-40 for a little insurance.

Comment: you're still lacing the area that you want to resettle wit toxic chemicals. If not from your tools then from exploded mines

Comment: @Hobbamok I don't recall reading that keeping the landscape toxin-free was a prerequisite of the OP's. The OP also didn't indicate what the intended purpose of the land would be after disarming the mines. The OP did say accomplishing the task quickly was a requirement. Are you jumping to a conclusion that resettlement is the intended purpose and that rapid resettlement takes priority over rapid disarmament?

Comment: Actually the territory needed to be transited in order to get to sea (for plot reasons, getting a very large amount of people to sea is imperative, and due to mountains, it would be extremely hard/slow to go around). The territory would need to be resettled afterwards, but that can wait decades or more. I will update my post to clarify this. 

Actually jellied liquid nitrogen, if it can detonate AT mines (as opposed to only AP) would sound incredible. If it can't, I can probably handwave something, but I'd like to look into whether this is actually maybe possible even now.

Comment: @Gnudiff There's a huge difference between "can we actually do this today?" and "is this entirely believable today?" I'm a fan of the later. Not so much the former. I'm not even sure where to start researching the practical engineering of jellied liquid N. But one thing I do know - the whole world thought it was impossible to frost the inside of a light bulb until Edison did it - but everybody wished it could be done.

Comment: If you just need a road then this is much less work than clearing the land for use - you might need 50m of width to put a 10m road through but that's still 20km of road per square km cleared.

Comment: @CongChen Per the OP's question, `We are talking vast areas - 100,000km2 or more.` And the OP wants it all cleared quickly.

Comment: Agreed @JBH in the main question but see comment above (40 mins previous to this one) which explains that only getting through is required at this time. Of course once roads are built exploitation will expand from the road network, driving priorities for clearing of land.

Comment: @CongChen That's a good point, but until Gnudiff updates his/her post, a mere mention in a comment isn't enough. This Stack has a tradition that changes to a question cannot invalidate answers. Therefore, the essence of the original question must remain. You are correct about one thing, almost any solution is cheaper than mine if all you need is a road cleared.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the drone bombs in the Ukraine. I think what a 'minefield' is may change.

You may still want to have a conventional clearly marked minefield to deny a region to a lot of low-level attackers. You might use this to surround an armed camp so civilians cannot get too close. The aim is not to blow a leg off a civilian but to threaten to do so if they get too close. That minefield has a known position, and the people who laid it should have taken care that it could be removed when it was not longer needed.

If you want to deny a larger region such as a forest to the enemy, then a mine is no longer something that waits for you to go and tread on it. If you look like the enemy, then the mines may come to you. That means you can defend a larger area with fewer mines. The mines may have separate detectors such as cameras hung in trees, and a wireless way of communicating to each other, so only one suicide mine will take on a particular target. A clever communication system where the mine going to attack can signal without revealing anything about where the other mines may be. All of this can easily be done with present-day tech.

The minesweeper going to have to look exactly like the target the mine is expecting. You may have to use old military vehicles. You may have to emulate radio conversation, or even real conversation to seem convincing. The mines ought to have a secret code that disarms them, because there is often little point denying territory to an enemy if you have denied it to yourself as well. But, if the enemy is still the enemy had has not told you the codes to turn it off, then finding these mines is going to be a long, slow slog, with no guarantee that you have found the last one. I think the mines should be intelligent to lie low though a shockwave or a nearby explosion, and wait for a real target.

If they have used low tech mines (maybe that's all they could make at the time) then you are still going to get them out one at a time. I cannot see the shockwave or any other sweeping technique working.

Think how you might design a mine. Do not try and make it too easy to disarm. Make it is good as you can. Then figure out how to beat it. Then try to figure out how to beat that. Then it will be realistic.

Comment: Mines in my story remain of near current-era conflicts, such as are used a lot in world at the moment.  Something similar to what is actually deployed in Ukraine by Russia currently: +100'000 km2 of minefields.  So, nothing intelligent in terms of mines, just an incredibly big load of dumb ones.  With present day technology getting rid of them might take hundreds of years -- I am wondering what near-future tech might be possible that would significantly reduce that time. Enemy is not an issue, the territory is ~empty. Resources and time are though. Tech as near current era as reasonable.

Comment: Tricky. Minesweeping has not changed much since WWII, except that you can have mines with no metal parts for a detector. You can have trucks with flails that sweep the ground, setting off anything with a simple trigger. I think the only real advance is cheap satnav that can record what has been swept.

Comment: Actually, that's probably a good answer. You need a modestly blast-proof robot with a satnav, and a collection of sticks. Each bit of ground that it hit with a stick can be crossed off the places where a mine can be. You don't have to prove the whole desert is free of mines overnight, but you do have to secure the areas around where people live and work, and provide up-to-date maps of what is safe and what is not.

Comment: Yes, you COULD replace static (very cheap) with mobile (very very expensive) mines, but you could also go the economically realistic route. We already have functioning detect-and-shoot systems and they're still not that widely used because they are too expensive to deploy in a large area AND fewer objects mean quicker disarmament

Comment: @HobbamokCould? It may have happened already. I read about mortar-like landmines that can fire themselves at a nearby target in the nineties. Drones and computer vision are cheap these days.

Comment: "The aim is not to blow a leg off a civilian but to threaten to do so".  The US (BLU-43) and Russians (PFM-1, which they loved putting in dolls for girls to pick up in Afghanistan) would beg to differ.

Answer (score 3):

### Fantastically light trigger force

Think how much air pressure you need to simulate a 20kg footstep onto a trigger. You simply cannot generate that much air pressure without devastating consequences. Such a shock wave would kill most life (including humans) in the application zone.

But imagine that --by intent or accident-- the trigger force required has decreased over time so only tiny fraction is now needed. Maybe a component has decayed. This is still very bad news for the local wildlife, of course. But now they are vulnerable to an ordinary catastrophically-damaging-but-not-lethal shock wave.

Imagine that the same decayed material has made the tilt-rods of antitank mines far easier to sway and trigger. Many might go off during a storm.

Also, temporary minefields (intentional degradation) are a old concept -- many NATO scatterable mine systems were designed to self-destruct after a period of time. Units were expected to record and recover their hand-laid mines, too. Unsupervised minefields are squandered resources.

Answer (score 3):

A quick googling showed me that it is [not impossible](https://www.swissinfo.ch/eng/sci-tech/electromagnetic-waves-used-to-detonate-landmines/29525168) to detonate landmines by inducing a current in their triggering mechanism from an external source via EM radiation.

If you can build the right kind of projector or EMP device, you could likely scale up to square kilometer scale, if the mines haven't been specifically hardened.

You would likely end up triggering most explosives (unless disabling an electronic trigger suffices to disable the mine), which will not be a great, but likely acceptable outcome, depending on mines per square meter.

This is probably closest to what you had in mind, as triggering an EMP certainly has an explosive nature, and is reasonably near future-tech to turn into the right directed energy weapon for the job.

There are of course some downsides to using large scale EM pulses in the wild, as you may end up disabling communications, sattelites, power lines, and general electronics within a much larger area than that being demined. And you really don't want one of those devices going off near any of your population centers on accident.

Comment: How much electronics are actually in land mines?  ISTM that you want them as simple as possible.

Comment: I wondered about using an Ekranoplan to produce an overpressure at ground level. The land mine does not necessarily need you to tread fully on the button. Possibly just treading on a corner of the case would be enough. In which case the overpressure on the case might do the same job. This would not work for a small path through the woods, but it might be useful to check hundreds of miles of dirt roads.

Answer (score 3):

### Blind bombing is too inefficient

While 1 giant bomb is SOUNDS efficient, it really is not.  While 1-20 million land mines across this whole region might be reasonable, this is still only an average of 10-200 mines per km^2.  Statistically, it would take 1000s if not 10s of thousands of kg of randomly dropped explosives just to find and trigger 1 mine! Using current mine destruction explosive weapons, this would have a cost of about 10 trillion dollars... and that is before you even account for the cost of the labor, logistics, and deployment platforms.

Instead you need to focus on FINDING the mines and disposing of them 1 at a time.  While finding and detonating millions of mines may sound daunting, it's still easier than blindly shooting up an area the size of Colorado and hoping you get them all.  For developing a future tech to solve this issue, don't focus on making a better bomb, make a better detection system.  Because once, you locate the bombs, removal is relatively trivial.

I would suggest a sort of low altitude aerial drone that can fly quickly over an area scanning the ground for mines using a ground penetrating radar.  GPRs can image buried objects including plastic AP mines at depths much greater than a typical landmine is buried.  Then image recognition software could sort out all the buried keys, coins, pipes, and other miscellaneous stuff from what is likely no more than 10-20 styles of mines.

With many drones able to fly at speeds in excess of 100kph, if you could scan a 1m wide area per pass, that means that each drone could cover a square km in just 10 hours of scanning.  By using AI image recognition, tessellated seam tracking, and GPS, your drone could record the entire area that they've searched and confirm with a very high degree of certainty, that they searched the whole area (unlike human teams that often leave gaps in thier search patterns); so, by the time you are done, you can confirm that 100% of your mined area has been scanned, and just mark any areas the drones could not reach for human crews to assess.  Every time your drones detect a mine, they can automatically upload it into a database for disposal.

While current GPR systems are not this fast, and such mine-sweeper drones may not exist yet, they would make a very plausible near future technology.

Now here is where your firepower comes in... because let's faced it, getting to use a giant bomb to take out a minefield sounds fun.  While I said that 10-200 mines per sqkm would be an average, most sq km will have few-to-zero mines. In all likelihood, you have lots of mines along important roads or natural passes where you can actually funnel enemy troops, and other places may just have a thin line of mines meant to guard an entrenched area, but outside of these places, there will not be a very high density of minefields. So, places where you do have mines, you may have well over 10,000 in a single sqkm. If your drones identify an area that is so dense in mines that traditional disarmament may be deemed too dangerous or costly. Firebombing or MCLICing a few specific areas like this may be the best way to go.  In this case, you are not ruining 100,000km of land with indiscriminate bombing, but rather a few of the worst places that were so densely mined that bombing makes since.  These places wont be ready for agriculture again any time soon, but you could use this method to make settling in the general area much safer.

But... a 20mm cannon may be better. MCLICing or fire bombing an area generally costs about 100 \$/m^2.  The problem here is that it is unlikely that the entire target zone of an area will have mines; so, if you find a row of 200 mines, 50m long, MCLICing it will still cost the full \$87,000 making your actual cost over 400 \$/m^2. Again, this is where your GPR imaging becomes so important.  Each time your drone IDs a mine, a sperate nearby automated cannon system could fire a single bullet into the ground to detonate the mine.  A 20mm Vulcan round should impart plenty enough force to detonate any mine, and they only cost $29 per round.  Currently, shooting mines is not often done because it is hard to aim a gun properly from far enough away to be safe, but if you are using an AI aimed riffle, then you can get very close to 1-bullet per detonation.

So, if you wanted to get the whole job done in 5 years, working only during the day, you would need about 250 teams consisting of:

- 1 A drone with GPR system (~\$20,000-50,000)
- 1 Self-aiming 20mm riffle (~\$20,000-30,000)
- 1-2 Technicians to operate the drone and weapon system (~\$200,000-800,000)
- 1 Jeep or similar vehicle for deployment (~\$30,000)
- Maintenance costs (~\$35,000-55,000)
- Electrical costs for the drones to fly 400,000km ea (~\$8,000-24,000)
- Fuel cost for Jeeps* (~\$2000-50,000)

**to drive to and from deployment zones can vary a LOT based on how you manage your logistics.*

Then, you pad your actual costs by about 300% to account for unforeseen circumstances, rough terrain, special areas where manual cleanup crews are needed, procurement, administrative costs, etc... and you arrive at a total project cost of about ~\$315,000,000-1,039,000,000 in today's equivalent currency: a pretty easy cost for a country with a decent economy to absorb.

Comment: "Think of these like flying metal detectors."  Anti-personnel mines are mostly plastic.  There would be *lots* of false positives.

Comment: @RonJohn While your general purpose metal detector only makes some noise if it passes within a few cm of something metal, archology grade metal detectors can fully map the metallic contents of the ground at depths of up to 60ft... while a 60ft deep scan is not necessary, being able to image metallic objects near the surface will be enough to use Image Recognition to detect the wiring and semiconductors in plastic cased AP mines. A degree of near-future tech is required to miniaturize and make this system able to scan as fast as described but it's not a far stretch from what is available today,

Comment: You're describing ground penetrating radar, which must be dragged across the ground.  Future tech that can fly a GP radar set is probably doable.  Pretty expensive, though. MCLIC would be cheaper.

Comment: @RonJohn MCLIC is an "economical" solution for quickly clearing a path in an already identified, minefield, but they still cost about $100 per square meter of coverage.  Blindly MCLICing the whole region would cost ~10 trillion dollars...   Even if one of these drones costs 10 million of dollars, every hour it spends ruling out mine fields will save you its entire cost in blind bombing.

Comment: @Nosajimiki the typical plastic AP mines (eg M14) don't have any metal, including wiring or semiconductors in them.  They are purely mechanical devices with a plastic diaphragm or similar triggering a striker onto a chemical detonator which initiates the main charge.  Some of the smart scatterable anti-tank munitions will have electronics, but those are the exception - most mines are made as cheaply as possible with the longest shelf-life possible, so circuitry and the associated batteries are avoided.

Comment: "they still cost about $100 per square meter of coverage."  This is why you only demine the important parts, and mark off the rest.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Good points, but I did a bit more research on the topic, and the "deep metal detectors" I read about are actually GPRs (Ground Penetrating Radars) and they can detect plastic as well.